# React native - firebase authentication not working even though the entered credentials are correct

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhKb2.png)I'm learning firebase authentication and I already created an account with credentials x & y on the firebase website, but when I enter those (correct) credentials,
the app jumps to the catch case and displays it's error message not the then  case which should be the credentials is correct case, Please check the image containg my code.

Comment: It could be a lot of things. Try to embed the code here in the question, check on the request error message, then we could probably figure out what happens.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The result should be 'success' since i'm entering the correct credentials

Comment: @HeriHeheSetiawanThe code is in the image

Comment: Code should appear in the question, not in an image. It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Additionally links break and if they do, it invalidates the question so it would be useless to future readers. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)